# How can I create a multi-valued refiner for a Business Data Catalog external content type?

Tags: search, bcs, multiple-values, refiner

This question regards a SharePoint 2010 instance using vanilla search.

I'm currently using a Business Data Catalog to pull records from a database table with an end-goal of displaying the records in search results.  Each record is a flat aggregate of the base entity and its related tables (Deals -> Deals Count, for example).

One field in the record is a concatenated list of strings.  When displayed in the search results, we would like this field to behave as a multi-valued field, allowing us to refine search results by entries in this string list.

I've tried looking into how this is normally accomplished, but I can't seem to locate any examples whatsoever.

- Is there a known way to accomplish this?
- If not, are there any resources which could help clarify what the actual problem is, and how it could be resolved?

P.S.: I am by no means a SharePoint expert, and am fairly unfamiliar with many of its components, so if further clarification would help or I'm asking for something nonsensical, please inform me so I can try to provide a clearer question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOB SharePoint 2010 does not have multi-value refiners.
I know of a [codeplex project](http://sprefiner.codeplex.com/) with multi-value refiners but haven't tested it, but you might want to give it a shot.

In short it splits the string, eg. red;yellow;blue, and look at it as seperate values. I can't see why this shouldn't work for BCS fields either.

[Here](http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/08/20/creating-a-custom-refinement-filter-generator.aspx) is a description of how to configure the refinement panel for using the multi-value refiner

More info on the refinement panel scheme [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819920.aspx)

Comment: Ahh, I believe this is indeed the missing piece of the puzzle.  Thanks! Accepting now, but will pend on other  answers before submitting bounty.

Comment: Quick note: SharePoint 2010 does support multi-value refiners; however, as far as I can tell, it _doesn't_ support the creation of multi-valued refiners from multi-valued fields, which is the problem that the codeplex project solves.